# Dart Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Family', - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add data from Firebase Firestore to a list with Provider. I'm getting an error though. I'm quite new to Provider, so I'm probably doing something silly.

"Dart Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Family',".

**family_view.dart**

```
class FamilyView extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget familyMember(BuildContext context) {
    var family = Provider.of<Family>(context);

    CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

    ref.doc(user.uid)..get().then((val) {
      family = val["family"];
      print(family);
    });

    return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(family[index]["name"]),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 2,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: family.length);
  }
```

family_provider.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Family with ChangeNotifier {
  List _family = [];

  List get family {
    return [..._family];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what value "family = val["family"];" has?

Comment: I'm not sure what it has, but I think it is equal: [{"name": "Killian"}]

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems with that code, if family is what you say it is which is a List that contains [{"name": "Killian"}] it should work.

I tried this and saw no problem

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
List<dynamic> family = [{'name': 'Killian'}, [{'name': 'Killian'}, {'name': 'Killian'}]];
return Scaffold(

  body: Center(
    child: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text(family[1][index]["name"]),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
    itemCount: family.length,))
  );    
}
```

What end up on the screen is a number of ListTiles that say Killian equal to the lenght of the family list.

Maybe you are receiving something that you dont expect.

Is there something i missed?

Comment: The data is coming from Firebase could that make a difference?

https://prnt.sc/13m1vae

Comment: Oh sorry, no wait it is receiving this whole document from Firebase

Comment: ah i see, the document from your picture right? let me see

Comment: try title: Text(family[1][index]["name"]),

Comment: "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Family'.
Try defining the operator '[]'." -  That's the error I get

Comment: That's weird, i dont get any errors, i'll get back to you if i come up with something

Comment: Maybe I am over complicating it, all I want to do is listen to that firebase document, and update the UI if there is changes to the document.

Comment: to listen to changes on firestore maybe it would be better if you used a stream builder, im not sure if right now your are listening to changes

Comment: I don't think I am, I just followed a very generic tut, maybe it is not suitable for my use case

Comment: Try searching how to subscribe to a firebase firestore and you should be on the right path :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find out what was the problem, but I think it is that the tut I followed was not suitable for my use case, so instead I used a Stream Builder.